# Using AsyncTask to load more than two images in daimajia-AndroidImageSlider with jsonData

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm using https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider with slider for **three images**.and here is what i've tried in my `AsyncTask` for load three image From `Json Data`:

```
public class AsyncHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        public ProgressDialog pDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading, Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            Integer result = 0;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection;

            try {
                /* forming th java.net.URL object */
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                /* for Get request */
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
                if (statusCode ==  200) {

                    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }

                    parseResult(response.toString());

                    result = 1;

                }else{

                    result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";

                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

            /* Download complete. Lets update UI */
            if (result == 1) {
                adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, feedItemList);
                mmRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                pDialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
```

Of course for load this we need to use this on `Oncreate`:

```
final String url = "http://url/Data.json"; //json data url
        new AsyncHttpTask().execute(url); //execute the json data
```

so, i have three image in my `JsonData`:

```
"Main-header": [
    {

    "HeaderImg1": "http://url/Main1.jpg",
    "Title": "title 1"
    },
    {
    "HeaderImg2": "http://url/Main2.jpg",
    "Title": "title 2"
    },
    {
    "HeaderImg3": "http://url/Main2.jpg",
    "Title": "title 3"
    }
  ]
```

// my JsonData is working witout any problem.But,

What can i do for show these three images in this slider as above `JsonData`?

**Edit:** here is what i've done with this on my Oncreate and this, worked fine but i need from Json data loaded:

```
mDemoSlider = (SliderLayout) findViewById(R.id.slider);
        HashMap<String, String> url_maps = new HashMap<>();
        url_maps.put("title1", "http://url/pic1.jpg");
        url_maps.put("title2", "http://url/pic3.jpg");
        url_maps.put("title3", "http://url/pic3.jpg");
        for (String name : url_maps.keySet()) {
            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(this);
            // initialize a SliderLayout
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image(url_maps.get(name))
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit);
            //add your extra information
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra", name);
            mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
        mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Right_Bottom);
        mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        mDemoSlider.setDuration(6000);
```

Any help Appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: you need to get the 3 images at once, is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: hi.because i'm using this slider, i dont think it's needed.see my last edit please.i added the orginal code for load three image.but i need to use this from JsonData and this is what i needed.

Comment: this is weird ! are you asking to display jsonData as :
"Main-header": [
    {

    "HeaderImg1": "http://url/Main1.jpg",
    "Title": "title 1"
    },
    {
    "HeaderImg2": "http://url/Main2.jpg",
    "Title": "title 2"
    },
    {
    "HeaderImg3": "http://url/Main2.jpg",
    "Title": "title 3"
    }
  ]

Comment: or do you need to loop through JsonData whithout using HashMap ?

Comment: `Main-header` is my **Array** in Json.what is weird on this codes? i need to show this three images in every slide on slider..

Comment: it seems, your second commend (loop through loading json data on this slider)i needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you are supposed to do it. Use this code in your Asynctask's onPostExecute method.

```
                arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                JSONObject jsonResponse;
                try {
                    jsonResponse = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("Main-header");

                    int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();
                    for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++)
                    {
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);


                        map.put(jsonChildNode.getString("Title"),jsonChildNode.getString("HeaderImg2"));
                        arraylist.add(map);
                        for(String name : map.keySet()){
                            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(MainActivity.this);

                            textSliderView
                                    .description(name)
                                    .image(map.get(name))
                                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                                    .setOnSliderClickListener(MainActivity.this);

                            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
                            textSliderView.getBundle()
                                    .putString("extra", name);

                            mDemoSlider.addSlider(textSliderView);
                        }
                        mDemoSlider.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.Accordion);
                        mDemoSlider.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
                        mDemoSlider.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
                        mDemoSlider.setDuration(4000);
                        mDemoSlider.addOnPageChangeListener(MainActivity.this);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
```